# Copy-paste from Google Docs edited in suggestion mode without deleted text

Tags: google-docs

When a Google Doc has been edited in suggestion mode, both added and deleted parts of text are marked up.

When I now mark a part of the document and copy/paste, the deleted sections are in included in the copied material, making the result generally garbled; both old deleted text and the replacement text are in the pasted text.  This is unlike the behaviour of Word and LibreOffice, where the deleted text is ignored when copying into a new environment, say a text editor. What is copied is essentially what would be copied if all the change suggestions were accepted.

Is there any way to get this behaviour with Google Docs? As a work-around I download the document as Word document, open in Word and copy/paste from there, but that's a huge pain, particularly when it's a long document, and I only want to copy a short paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the exact same question as you did, that is how I stumbled into this page. It may be too late, but I just found out that if you go to "Tools" on the Google docs menu ( between "Format" and "Help" there is an option to "preview all suggested edits" which allows you to copy-paste the doc with the applied changes somewhere else. You can also just accept all suggestions through the same menu...

Hope this belated response helped

Comment: This works - thanks a lot for taking time to share. I have to take one more click. Go to "Tools/Review Suggested edits", then in the pull-down menu choose 
"preview - accept all".  
To be really precise maybe you could edit your answer accordingly (if this is indeed what you see; otherwise I guess there are different versions of Google Docs)